# optimized way of doing this so its faster?

Tags: lua

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
table.insert(out, table.remove( tbl, math.random(#tbl) ) )
```

ive tried doing it like

```
out[#out + 1] = tbl
tbl[#math.random(#tbl)] = nil
```

Comment: `local i = math.random(#tbl); out[#out+1] = tbl[i]; tbl[i] = tbl[#tbl]; tbl[#tbl] = nil`

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly more efficient than `table.insert`:

```
out[#out + 1] = table.remove(tbl, math.random(#tbl))
```